# Tmux quits whenever I try to type the capital letter "Z"- is there a workaround?

Tags: tmux

Tmux quits whenever I try to type the capital letter "Z". That is, SHIFT-Z quits tmux.

Tmux exits with 0 return code.

Tested with version 3.0a on CentOS. If I can't upgrade the tmux version, is there a workaround?

Comment: What is the output of `tmux list-keys -T root | grep Z`?

Comment: I'm an idiot! it includes ` bind -n Z kill-session` -- I must have blindly copied that from somewhere. User error! If you convert your comment to an answer I can mark it correct. Perhaps someone else in the internet blindly copied the same .tmux.conf.

Answer (score 1):

The tmux.conf had this line:

```
bind -n Z kill-session
```

so tmux was just doing what I was telling it to do.

As @KamilMaciorowski suggested, `tmux list-keys -T root | grep <the keybinding that is weird>` is helpful in diagnosing this sort of thing.